# how to let xterm have geometry of 80x1 after disabling decorations?

Tags: xterm, wmctrl, window-decorations, window-geometry

I use this to toggle-decorations: https://gist.github.com/muktupavels/d03bb14ea6042b779df89b4c87df975d

if I start `xterm -geometry 80x1` it will have 1 height (in xterm TEXT lines, not in screen dots), but the moment I disable decorations it will have as many lines as it can fit in that window while it had decorations: 3

after I disable decorations, I cant use the mouse cursor to resize it anymore...

I use the window id $nWID I get from `xwininfo`.

if I use this command: `wmctrl -i -r $nWID -e "0,200,45,500,1"` it will NOT let me set xterm height to less than 2 xterm TEXT lines (this command uses screen dots)

`xtermcontrol --geometry=80x1` does nothing (why it wont work at all? neither `xtermcontrol --geometry=80x50` works...) and I would have to use it from inside that xterm, I cant point to that xterm by that window ID right? I saw no option on xtermcontrol that would allow that.

I use this special xterm with nethogs and keep it above other windows, but I am not able to let it have less than 2 xterm text lines of height, and that is somewhat complicated to see windows below it.

are there any terminal alternatives that would let me have non-decorated window with just one line?
obs.: rxvt (or URxvt) didn't work

btw.: ubuntu 18.04, not all terminals are available to this version of ubuntu like the great `mrxvt` :(

Comment: The window manager controls the size (which explains why `xtermcontrol` does not help).  You'll have to solve that by asking the window manager to change the size...

Comment: `wmctrl` isn't for that? I think it makes the WM do that right? but it still fails in the end, like xterm could be forcing a minimum of 2 lines after `wmctrl` for some reason.

Comment: no - xterm doesn't.   Via `xtermcontrol`, xterm *asks* the window manager if it's okay to use a given size, and the window manage *decides* and tells xterm how big it's going to be.  Using `wmctrl`, it *advises* the window manager, who's (still the boss) free to ignore (or in the case of gnome-session, misunderstand) the advice.  The window manager's the place to go.

Comment: "gnome-session, misunderstand" aww... it means it may get fixed for gnome-terminal? :(, it is working with it now.

Comment: The `wmctrl` command might be the problem, too.  But (running on macOS) the escape sequences used by `xtermcontrol` got me a 1-line xterm (not very useful, but just to check my memory).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using gnome-terminal. It accepts `xtermcontrol` commands properly too.

gnome-terminal --zoom=0.75 --title "SomeTitleEasyToFind" --hide-menubar --geometry=80x1 -- bash -c "FUNC"

the exported FUNC will contain all commands to setup this terminal geometry (position, size) and decorations, all in the right order, and all before the final call to run nethogs.